# Notation of the vector: $\mathbf{\hat b}=(\mathbf{\hat i}-2 \mathbf{\hat k}) \times(\mathbf{\hat i}+3 \mathbf{\hat j}-4 \mathbf{\hat k})$

Tags: linear-algebra

What does it means when a vector is written as the following?

My professor explained it as:
$$
\vec{b}=\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
\hat{\imath} & \hat{\jmath} & \hat{k} \\\\ 1 & 0 & -2 \\\\ 1 & 3 & -4
\end{array}\right|=6 \hat{i}+2 \hat{\jmath}+3 \hat{k},
$$
but I don't understand it. Could someone explain the method behind this?

Comment: Look up how to expand a 3 by 3 determinant

Comment: $n$ and $c$ should be $i$ and $k$ on the right hand side.

Comment: Thanks, Ross it's fixed now.

Comment: This is technically an abuse of notation. That might be the cause of confusion. The unit vectors don't strictly make sense as entries when mixed with reals. The implied mathematical operations do hold up though making it a useful mnemonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Cross Product (MathWorld)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html) or [Cross Product (Wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) for a definition of the cross product of two vectors written as a determinant. In general the notation, in the form of a determinant, is
\begin{align}
\vec{A} \times \vec{B} &= \left|\begin{array}{ccc}
\hat{\imath} & \hat{\jmath} & \hat{k} \\\\ a_{1} & a_{2} & a_{3} \\\\ b_{1} & b_{2} & b_{3} \end{array}\right| \\
&= (a_{2} b_{3} - a_{3} b_{2} ) \, \hat{i} - (a_{1} b_{3} - a_{3} b_{1}) \, \hat{j} + (a_{1} b_{2} - a_{2} b_{1} ) \, \hat{k}.
\end{align}

In the current problem the vectors are $\vec{A} = \hat{i} - 2 \, \hat{k}$ and $\vec{B} = \hat{i} + 3 \hat{j} - 4 \, \hat{k}$ which gives
\begin{align}
\vec{b} &= \vec{A} \times \vec{B} = \left|\begin{array}{ccc}
\hat{\imath} & \hat{\jmath} & \hat{k} \\\\ 1 & 0 & -2 \\\\ 1 & 3 & -4 \end{array}\right| \\
&= (0 - (-6) ) \, \hat{i} - (-4 - (-2)) \, \hat{j} + 3 \, \hat{k} \\
&= 6 \, \hat{i} + 2 \, \hat{j} + 3 \, \hat{k}.
\end{align}

Comment: May be less confusing if you consistently call the vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ rather than $\vec {b_1}$ and $\vec {b_2}$